# How to avoid to run the event "mouseout" while another element was moving in?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating my custom animation for some divs while hovering. Like this:

```js
$('.d1').on('mouseover', function () {
  $('.d2').animate({ 'margin-top': '-100px' }, 500);
});

$('.d1').on('mouseout', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
.d1, .d2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```

I'm getting a trouble: I lost the event `mouseover` while the box `d2` was moving through `d1` and the event `mouseout` was caught:

[image: 1]

I don't want to hit the event `mouseout` while moving `d2`. Also I want to use the event when the cursor is really `out` from `d1`.

My question: Can I ignore to run the event `mouseout` while moving `d2`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use the CSS declaration `pointer-events: none;` to stop `d2` from "blocking" the mouseover `d1`

```js
$('.d1').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.d2').addClass("noEvents").animate({
    'margin-top': '-100px'
  }, 500, function() {
    $('.d2').removeClass("noEvents");
  });
});

$('.d1').on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
.d1,
.d2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.noEvents {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```

As mentioned in the comments, if there are no events on the `d2` element, this could be simplified to just adding the CSS to the `.d2` style, with no JS changes.

```js
$('.d1').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.d2').animate({
    'margin-top': '-100px'
  }, 500);
});

$('.d1').on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
.d1,
.d2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: blue;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```

Comment: For a couple of seconds...you could just put it on the blue one.

Comment: @VXp True, but I was assuming this is a simplified example and there may also be events on the `d2` element.

Comment: I know, better this way, was just looking from the "short-as-possible" perspective, depends on the OP's desire though, but still upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setTimeout function to make sure d2 was moved completely

```js
$('.d1').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('.d2').animate({ 'margin-top': '-100px' }, 500);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.d1').on('mouseout', function () { $(this).css('background-color', 'green'); })
    }, 500)
});
```

```css
.d1, .d2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```